# MySQL Left Join with fundamentally differently structured tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a mysql query, that already left joins another table and that works fine. I now had to left join yet another table. At first this seemed to work too. 
But the thing is: The value i'm matching the join on is in one table singulary/indexical, but on the other table it emerges multiply. 
I'm very bad at articulating this, even tho it's a rather simple set up.

So i made a fiddle to visualize what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/fesoLvy4/2/

When i now do my usual left join routine and put the mysql_query into PHP:

```
<?php
echo "  <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Dog</th>
            <th>Species</th>
            <th>Properties</th>
          </tr>";

     while($data = mysql_fetch_row($mysql_leftjoin_query)){
  echo "  <tr>
            <td>$data[0]</td>
            <td>$data[1]</td>
            <td>$data[2]</td>
          </tr>
        </table>"; } 
?>
```

only the first entry of the left joined table gets into table - $data[3] contains only the first value of the second table that matches, but i want all of the entries that match in $data[3]. Please have a look at the fiddle, I'm struggling to put this into words but i think it's a very simple set up.
I think it has something to do with php's mysql_fetch_row but I can't put my finger on it.

For completeness, here is my MySQL query (simplified):

```
$mysql_leftjoin_query = mysql_query("SELECT MASTER.animal, MASTER.species, BI.properties

 FROM        `XYZ_MASTER`  MASTER
    LEFT JOIN  `XYZ_BOARD_INFO` BI

        ON (MASTER.animal = BI.animal)");
```

Now, BI.properties should count all the entries of BI where MASTER.animal and BI.animal match and not just the first single entry.

Comment: Did you try to execute your `php` code? Is there supposed to be `echo`?

Comment: The left join works as expected. See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce3de/1). But the PHP code you provide is not valid. It cannot run.

Comment: No, I'm sorry @akasummer, my fault, i didn't provide the whole php and simplyfied it, so it'd be easier to read (it's quite exhaustive otherwhise). The php works fine, as i said, i'm able to get the results i want - with the exception, that i only get the first value of the second table that matches the 'joined on' value.

Comment: @trincot sorry this is my fault. I simplyfied the php for this post, because it's very extensive otherwhise. The php is completely valid (in the original) - i have a structural problem! Please see the fiddle if you'd be so kind, my problem is described there. How can i sculpt the query so that there is one index value in one table but that has multiple counterparts in the other table. And i want all of the multiple counterparts, not just the first row.

Comment: Please check my fiddle. It shows that the left join works correctly. You have not demonstrated in your question that you have any other result.  Please provide code that actually reproduces the problem. Your fiddle is actually just a presentation of three tables, but that is just hard coded. If you execute the SQL like in your PHP code it DOES return mutliple values from the left joined table.

Comment: @trincot No it does not! mysql_fetch_row returns exactly 1 row out of data from both tables. My problem is, that there are several rows from one table that should be transmitted into a single `<td>` in that single table row.

My fiddle shows with table 3 the table i WANT TO achieve, but yet haven't. Table 1 and Table 2 show my set up. Do you know what i mean? I can't put all the `properties` for `dog` in table 2 into one single `<td>` in table 3 with `mysql_fetch_row`

Comment: It does, the second value will end up in another row of course. But I now think I understand what you are asking: you want the multiple values not to occur in different rows, but concatenated and comma-separated into one value. Why did you not talk about concatenation and comma-separation? It would make things clear from the start.

Comment: @trincot exactly, yes!!! Thank you for phrasing this :D - I'm sorry, I 'tumbled' into programming in an internship but had to learn everything by myself and ugh I guess i'm not the best autodidact. Hence I don't quite know how to articulate code issues.. // I didn't know the word concatenation f.e. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are maybe looking for the [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```sql
SELECT     MASTER.animal, MASTER.species, 
           group_concat(BI.properties separator ', ') as Properties
FROM       MASTER
LEFT JOIN  BOARD_INFO BI
       ON (MASTER.animal = BI.animal)
GROUP BY   MASTER.animal, MASTER.species
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce3de/3).

Output of the SQL is:

```
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+
| animal | species | properties                    |
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+
| dog    | mammal  | has ears, has a tail, has fir |
| cat    | mammal  | meows, hunts birds            |
| turtle | reptile | (null)                        | 
+--------+---------+-------------------------------+
```

Your PHP can stay like it is.

Comment: WONDERFUL, this seems exactly what i was looking for!!! Thank you so much already and thank you for struggling with my through my restricted articulation :D I will just try it out and then accept it as answer!